# how to check if all my 5 files are present inside a folder using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 5 files each stored in two folders in blob storage, I need to check if all 5 files are present in both folders . If yes then execute rest of the pipeline, else wait until all 5 files are placed in the folder.

How to achieve this using ADF

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get meta data activity to get the file details within a folder .

So the flow would be use:

1. untill activity
2. within Untill, use get meta data activity (2) one for each folder and set a variable once all 10 files are there

Comment: metadata activity is asking for a dataset to be present , is their a way i can provide folder structure?

Comment: https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-activity
https://azurelib.com/how-to-use-getmetadata-activity/
these 2 blogs should help

Answer (score 0):

1. Create dataset for your blob storage
2. Create pipeline with:

- Get Metadata childitems on your container - it has an output.count property
- IF activity to carry out other tasks IF count >= 5

3. Create a trigger for this pipeline with type "Storage Events" that runs on blob created event